# How to save an UIButton image using UserDefaults?

Tags: swift

I want to save an UIButton image inside UserDefaults and retrieve it with a key later on in my code. The UIImage comes from a tuple that is being used by an UIPickerView.

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

@IBOutlet weak var topCurrencyPicker: UIPickerView!

var topPickerOptions = [
    (symbol: String, name: String, sign: String, flag: UIImage)]()

func createTopAndBottomCurrency() {
    let topUserIndex = topCurrencyPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
    let topUserChoice = money.currencyISOCode[topUserIndex]
    userCurrencyChoice = Currencies(top: topUserChoice, bottom: bottomUserChoice)

// Save user pickerViews Choice
    defaults.set(topUserIndex,
                 forKey: ExchangePreferencesVC.topExPickerKey)
    defaults.set(userCurrencyChoice.top.sign,
                 forKey: ExchangePreferencesVC.topExSignKey)
    defaults.set(userCurrencyChoice.top.symbol,
                 forKey: ExchangePreferencesVC.topExSymbolKey)
}
```

Is it then possible to save this UIImage as easily as a String can be?

Comment: Do you really need to save the **image** physically? Isn't it sufficient to save a name or an URL?

Comment: I can save it by its Assets.xcassets name if needed, as long as I have my image back where I would like it to be.

Comment: That's definitely the better choice. An assets name is required to be unique.

Answer (score -1):

**Swift 4.2**

```
public final class PreferencesService {
  private let userDefaults: UserDefaults

  init(userDefaults: UserDefaults = .standard) {
    self.userDefaults = userDefaults
  }

  var avatar: UIImage? {
    get {
        guard let filename = documentsDirectory?.appendingPathComponent(#function, isDirectory: false) else {
            return nil
        }
        return UIImage(contentsOfFile: filename.path)
    }
    set {
        guard let filename = documentsDirectory?.appendingPathComponent(#function, isDirectory: false) else {
            return
        }
        guard let newImage = newValue else {
            try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: filename)
            return
        }
        if let data = newImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0) {
            try? data.write(to: filename)
        }
    }
  }

  private var documentsDirectory: URL? {
      let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
      return paths.first
  }

  var coolDown: Bool {
      get { return userDefaults.bool(forKey: #function) }
      set { userDefaults.set(newValue, forKey: #function) }
  }

  var lastVisited: Date {
      get { return userDefaults.object(forKey: #function) as? Date ?? Date() }
      set { userDefaults.set(newValue, forKey: #function) }
  }

}
```

Better to store image in Document Directory.
If needed to Store UserDefaults - you can store it like Data.

**Usage**

```
PreferencesService().avatar = button.image(for: .normal)
```

**Bonus:** Note how to store simply other types Bool, Date, String.

Comment: There is a lot of redundant code. The `documents` directory is guaranteed to exist so returning an optional and the related `guard` statements are pointless.